# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError while passing large CSV File to Mapper in Hadoop

Tags: java, multithreading, hadoop

getting issue while putting Mapper output data into HBASE table .

```
   15/09/21 17:19:12 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
    15/09/21 17:19:12 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local_0001
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:640)
    at   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addThread(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:681)
    at   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addIfUnderCorePoolSize(ThreadPoolExecuto    r.java:706)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:650)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.processBatchCallback(HConnectionManager.java:1555)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.processBatch(HConnectionManager.java:1418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.flushCommits(HTable.java:918)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.doPut(HTable.java:774)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.put(HTable.java:749)
    at hbaseAdmin.HbaseConnection.createColumnQualifier(HbaseConnection.java:74)
    at hbaseMapReduce.MapperClass.map(MapperClass.java:31)
    at hbaseMapReduce.MapperClass.map(MapperClass.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:212)
15/09/21 17:19:12 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 12% reduce 0%
```

Mapper Code :-

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context output) throws            IOException, InterruptedException
    {

     String values=value.toString();
     String[] arr=values.split(",");
     String Date=arr[0];
      System.out.println(output.getCurrentKey()+"" +output.getCurrentValue());
     System.out.println(Thread.activeCount());
     HbaseConnection.createColumnQualifier("10","NASDEQDATA25","StokeData",Date,high);
```

Note :- SYSOUT Thread.activeCount() returns me 581 .
I am ruuninng my LocalJob in VMWare Player and using apache hadoop 1.X version

Comment: I think , every output of mapper you are creating new connection to Hbase. Can you show the code of createColumnQualifier method

Comment: public static void createColumnQualifier(String rowid,String TableName,String ColumnFamily1,String ColumnQual,String Columnval) throws IOException{
   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
 table = new HTable(config, TableName);
   Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowid));
    p.add(Bytes.toBytes(ColumnFamily1), Bytes.toBytes(ColumnQual),Bytes.toBytes(Columnval));
  table.put(p);

Comment: I dont think i am connecting everytime . Can you please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Move the creation of config and table objects to the setup method. Setup method calls only once before any calls of map methods. Try to avoid creating objects in map methods because they call very often and provide a heavy load on GC

Comment: thanks # maxteneff  : your suggestion helped me alot .